# Do I want to mark my Visual Studio project as managed by Subversion?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I'm using AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2008.

When I add a new project to SVN, I am asked the following:

> Would you like to mark 'My Project' as managed by Subversion?

The answer is so obviously yes - why would I add the project to SVN if I didn't want it to be managed by SVN - that I figure there must be some other meaning to the question.

Does anyone know what this question means or if the answer I give has any practical consequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=361505),

> If you mark the solution as 'Managed by Subversion' Visual Studio will
>   automatically enable AnkhSVN and TFS when required.